# python encoding result from API request

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests, subprocess

I am using an API request to retrieve data from an external site. But when the data includes a foreign character, the code fails.

---

In a git bash shell, I can run

```
curl -s https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=unique%3Aprints%20e%3ALTR%20%21%22Rosie%20Cotton%20of%20South%20Lane%22
```

to see the response and I notice it includes čková as part of the data returned.

at first I was trying to use

```
command= "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=unique%3Aprints%20e%3ALTR%20%21%22Rosie%20Cotton%20of%20South%20Lane%22"
completed_process= subprocess.run(['curl','-s',command] , capture_output=True , text=True , timeout=5 )
```

and receive the following error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (_readerthread):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tiera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\tiera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tiera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1552, in _readerthread
    buffer.append(fh.read())
                  ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tiera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 13400: character maps to <undefined>
```

I also tried using python requests to see if that would fix the problem

```
            command= "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=unique%3Aprints%20e%3ALTR%20%21%22Rosie%20Cotton%20of%20South%20Lane%22"
            apiRes= requests.get( command , stream=True )
            print('DEBUG:','čková'.encode('utf-8'))
            print( "STATUS:",apiRes.status_code )
            print( 'CONTENT:',apiRes.headers['content-type'])
            print( 'ENCODING:',apiRes.encoding )
```

and receive the following

```
DEBUG: b'\xc4\x8dkov\xc3\xa1'
STATUS: 200
CONTENT: application/json; charset=utf-8
ENCODING: utf-8
```

if I follow the above with

```
            print( 'JSON:',apiRes.json() )
```

I receive the error:

```
JSON: Error executing command: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 14019: character maps to <undefined>
```

if I instead try

```
            print( 'TEXT:',apiRes.text )
```

the error received is:

```
TEXT: Error executing command: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 13381: character maps to <undefined>
```

---

Note - if the result of the API call doesn't include foreign characters, then no errors are received. For example, using

```
command= 'https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=unique%3Aprints%20e%3AUNF%20%21%22Forest%22'
```

works as expected for both the subprocess.run and the requests.get versions.

As described above, I initially tried subprocess.run curl to make the API request. When that had difficulty with the foreign characters received and my searches for a solution didn't seem to work, I tried using the requests library and trying requests.get - but still decoding errors with regards to those foreign characters returned.
I also tried the .text option to the response from the requests.get call to access the underlying response, but that also failed.

Comment: The problem is just in the `print`ing. Your console/stdout doesn't run on UTF-8 or any other compatible encoding. `print('DEBUG:', 'čková')` should confirm that.

Comment: Thank you. That solves my problem with the requests library.

I would rather run using subprocess.run (so that the requests library doesn't need to be installed), If anyone else has a solution for that, it would be appreciated.